# Deleting a row in grid view,in which data and column names are given from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to delete a row from an GridView,i Used an different approach ,all the things are done in code behind.I tried To delete a row when user clicks the Delete link button but the row row is not getting deleted, I tried In row deleting event but i am getting a stack overflow exception.

Adding Column Names:

```
DataTable dtToGrid = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = dtToGrid.Columns.Add("S.No", typeof(int));
dc.AutoIncrement = true;
dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dtToGrid.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
dtToGrid.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
dtToGrid.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
dtToGrid.Columns.Add("RatePer Unit", typeof(string));
dtToGrid.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
Session["dtToGrid"] = dtToGrid;
```

Adding Row Values:

```
double sum = 0;

grd.Visible = true;

DataTable dtToGrid = (DataTable)Session["dtToGrid"];

DataRow drToGrid = dtToGrid.NewRow();

drToGrid["ItemName"] =ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value;
drToGrid["Quantity"] = txtQty.Text;
drToGrid["Unit"]=Unit.Value;
drToGrid["RatePer Unit"]=costperunit.Value;
drToGrid["Amount"]=txtAmount.Text;                                  

dtToGrid.Rows.Add(drToGrid);

grd.DataSource = dtToGrid;
grd.DataBind();
for (int x = 0; x < grd.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    sum += Convert.ToDouble(grd.Rows[x].Cells[5].Text);
}
if (totalAmountINcludingTax.Text == " ")
{
    sum = (sum * Convert.ToDouble(Tax.Value)) / 100 + sum;
    totalAmountINcludingTax.Text = sum.ToString();
}
else
{
    sum = (sum * Convert.ToDouble(Tax.Value)) / 100 +Convert.ToDouble( totalAmountINcludingTax.Text);
    totalAmountINcludingTax.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Row Deleting:

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int Prod_Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        grd.DeleteRow(Prod_Id);
    }
}
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
    onrowdeleting="grd_RowDeleting" onrowcommand="grd_RowCommand">

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete"  runat="server" CommandName="delete" title="Delete"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you Want to Delete this Record?');">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: you have declared  onrowdeleting="grd_RowDeleting" and trying to handle deletion in onrowcommand="grd_RowCommand"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the same logic as Add Row on Delete Row as well.
Basically find the data row to be deleted, remove from data table and rebind.

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int Prod_Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);        

        DataTable dtToGrid = (DataTable)Session["dtToGrid"];

        DataRow rowToBeDeleted = dtToGrid.Rows.Where(r=>r["Prod_Id"] == Prod_Id.ToString());

        if (rowToBeDeleted != null)
        {
          dtToGrid.Rows.Remove(rowToBeDeleted);

          grd.DataSource = dtToGrid;
          grd.DataBind();

          // do your summation logic.
        }
    }
}
```